# Unity 3d Vuforia not displaying 3d model target object

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I feel like this is as basic as it gets but I have been stuck for hours. I created a simple project using the Vuforia plugin for Unity and added in an ARCamera, Image, and Model Target.

All the project assets were downloaded from the Asset Store called "Vuforia Core Samples".

**Desired functionality** |
When the camera see's the trackable image of the astronaut it should then display the 3d model of the space rover.

**Actual behavior** |
The astronaut image that is being tracked is recognized however the space rover is not displayed. I can see that in the logs.

```
Trackable Astronaut found
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
DefaultTrackableEventHandler:OnTrackableStateChanged(Status, Status)    (at Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs:62)
```

If I change the model target object to a 3d shape like a cube, everything works as expected. I feel like I'm missing something super basic.

Heres a screen shot of my unity project
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because image target and model targets are completely different. Model target is used for tracking physical objects using their models. Image targets are used to track markers or images. If you just wanna render space rover remove all scripts like `model Target Behavior` and `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` on model targets.

Comment: Nice! You are absolutely right. I unchecked all scripts (3 total) and there was the rover. Thank you sir!